# FreeBSD and tunefs(8): minfree option

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, ufs

The minimum free space threshold in FreeBSD is 8% which I think is too high. In a 1 TB Hard Drive, 80 GB of space is unusable. I need some more space in my hard drive.  I want to reduce this percentage to 2% or 1% or even no minimum threshold at all, is it safe to do so? I mean:

```
# tunefs -m 2 /dev/ada0p5
```

Comment: yes it is safe...

Answer (score 0):

Reserved free space need for optimal filesystem performance. I don't recommend to reduce `minfree` unless you need high capacity with very low read/write speed, e. g. for backups.